# MSB4062: “Typescript.Tasks.CheckFileSysytemCaseSensitive” task couldn't be loaded from the assembly

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, msbuild, azureportal

While setting up a project, getting this error on `npm run build`:

> C:..\src\packages\Microsoft.Portal.Tools.5.0.303.3330\build\TypeScript\tools\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(219,5): error MSB4062: The "TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive"
>   task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:..\src\packages\Microsoft.Portal.Tools.5.0.303.3330\build\TypeScript\build..\tools\net45\TypeScript.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
>   [C:..\src\Default\Extension\Extension.csproj]

Package.json

```
  {
  "name": "extensiondev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "restore": "npm install --no-optional && nuget install ./packages.config",
    "build": "msbuild.exe ./Extension.csproj /m /p:RunBundlerInDevMode=true /t:Rebuild /flp1:logfile=msbuild.log /flp2:logfile=msbuild.err;errorsonly /flp3:logfile=msbuild.wrn;warningsonly",
    "serve": "node ./node_modules/@../portalhostingservice/DevServer/DevServer.js -s",
    "start": "npm run restore && npm run build && npm run serve",
    "watch": "cd ./node_modules/.bin && tsc.cmd -b ../../tsconfig.json -w --extendedDiagnostics",
    "release": "msbuild.exe ./Extension.csproj /m /p:RunBundlerInDevMode=false;Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild /flp1:logfile=msbuild.log /flp2:logfile=msbuild.err;errorsonly /flp3:logfile=msbuild.wrn;warningsonly"
  },
  "author": "..",
  "license": "..",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@../portalhostingservice": "1.182.*",
    "typescript": "3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the `packages.json` file with us? Did `npm run build` use MSBuild to build a new project?

Comment: Also, what version of VS did you use?  If you built setup project, you should use `devenv xxx.sln /build`. Did you use `npm run build` to build setup project which contains another project called `Extension`. If so, what your project type of the `Extension` project?  Besides, make sure that you have installed `Typescript sdk` in VS IDE. You should provide more detailed info about your issue.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Attached Package.json, VS Version: 16.6.0. Yes, I encountered this issue while running npm run build. I was able to build the extension within the IDE but not on Windows Powershell or anywhere outside the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the detailed info with us.

> MSB4062: “Typescript.Tasks.CheckFileSysytemCaseSensitive” task
>   couldn't be loaded from the assembly

The **reason** is that when you call **Windows Powershell**, you use another wrong **MSBuild** version rather than the related VS MSBuild version.

When you call **Windows Powershell** to build VS projects, you should config the right **MSBuild** path into **System Environment Variables** while [VS Developer Powershell](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/cjof4m/developer_powershell_for_vs_2019_what_does_it_do/) and [Developer Command Prompt for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) already contains the necessary development environment(the runtime required by the corresponding workspace and required DLLS for the corresponding project), so you can build in it.

**Since** you built the extension project successfully in VS IDE, I think you think use a wrong MSBuild version like `Framework MSBuild version` which does not contain the related development environment.

You should use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` which is used by **VS IDE** during the process.

**Solution**

**1)** check **PATH** system environment variables and delete the previous path.

**2)** Instead, input `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx\MSBuild\Current\Bin` into **PATH**, and then you can use Windows Powershell to build your project successfully.